# Why is GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS much smaller than GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, textures, texture2d

For texture sizes greater than `GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS`, I have to use an array of single textures instead of one texture array. No problem for me.
I'm just wondering whats the reason behind making `GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS` so much smaller than `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`?

edit: this can be deleted

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS basically describes how many 2D texture you can have, while GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE describes how large each of the 2D texture can be. It doesn't really make sense to compare them against each other.

Comment: Regarding *For texture sizes greather than GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS i have to use an array of single textures*: Given that GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS >= 256 in OpenGL 4, I highly doubt that you can even bind 256 single textures at the same time (GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS >= 48).

Comment: @BDL: "*Given that GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS >= 256 in OpenGL 4*" It's 2048 in GL 4.6. And combined image units is 80.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i mis understood the two GL params. there are no different size limitations between single texture2D and texture2DArray

Answer (score 4):

> For texture sizes greater than GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS

I believe you have mis-understood what this limitation means. This is not like `GL_MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE`, which is a limitation on all axes of a 3D texture. It is a limitation on the number of *array elements* in a 2D array texture. When you call `glTexImage3D/TexStorage3D`, the limitation applies to the `depth` parameter *only*, not the "size".

The `width/height` limit is still governed by `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`.

Comment: you are right. i mis understood the two GL params. there are no different size limitations between single texture2D and texture2DArray

Comment: does this mean if the max texture size limit is 2048x2048, and if the `GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS ` is 2048, you can have a 2048x2048 texture , and  2048 of them, 2048 textures with 2048x2048 size?

Comment: @MaYue: So long as it has sufficient memory for such a texture, yes.